# How should I refactor so that responsibility for a geocoding service is shared appropriately?

Tags: refactoring

First, some background. I have an application that requires the use of several external geocoding providers which I don't control. It uses a central service layer inside the application to dispatch to the appropriate provider.

I have a number of classes that are arranged in this way:

- **GeocodingService**: Responsible for dispatching a request to geocode something to an appropriate provider.

  - Has one public method, `geocode`, that accepts a **GeocodingService::Request** and returns a **GeocodingService::Response**.
  - Each response includes: the latitude of the geocoded query, the longitude of the geocoded query, and a list of address components for the address where the query was found (e.g., an address component for "123", one for "Main Street", one for "Paris", and so on).
- **GeocodingService::AddressComponent**: A single segment of an address that contains the segment's name, its abbreviation, and its kinds. For example, France has a name of `France`, an abbreviation of `FR`, and is a `country` and a `political` segment.

  - AddressComponent is responsible for checking that the types an instance is set with are not outside the boundaries of certain tracked types.
- **Address**: Domain model for addresses, containing both a preferred mailing address (a list of string lines) and a list of address components (a list of GeocodingService::AddressComponents).

My question is: **where should AddressComponent live -- as a service class (like it does now), or with my other domain models?**

- If it lives **in the service**, then life is straightforward. But that seems wrong, because now a domain model has to depend on a service's definition of an address, and it seems like they should be independent.
- If it lives as a **full-fledged domain object**, then doesn't that mean that the service is now coupled to a domain object? That also seems undesirable.

How do I resolve this impasse?

Answer (score 1):

Just because AddressComponents are inferred from external data provided by a service doesn't mean they aren't first class domain objects in your domain model.
Imagine you write another application in the same domain - wouldn't it be nice if you could reuse your domain layer without having to worry about Services ? I mean, the new application could get AddressComponent data from anywhere, its own database for instance. An AddressComponent wouldn't necessarily be linked to a Service.

So I'd choose option 2, and if you're concerned about your service instantiating a domain object, maybe you could introduce another object that does the creation - a Factory for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need either an Adapter or Builder to construct your Address domain object from the GeocodingService::AddressComponent(s).  This is the point where you loosely couple the components while maintaining separation of concerns and cohesiveness.